# Width:100% without Position:absolute/fixed

Tags: css

By using the property position:absolute; I have to mention the correct size of all layers (in my case 3 layers "#header", "#mybody", "#footer") where in my website #mybody's height is dynamic. So, I need #footer's position should be something like relative but using relative I am unable to set with:100%; Even if I set width:100% I am not getting complete 100% using relative. However I am getting 100% using absolute but I can't use absolute for above reason(s). Also I don't want footer to be fixed. How can I set my footer's width to 100% without using absolute or fixed position? Using width:100% with other than absolute or fixed doesn't resulting complete 100% to me.

Code:

## mheadf {

```
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:35px;
border:thin solid black;
```

}

## mbody {

```
position:relative;
width:800px;
height:500px;
border:thin solid black;
```

}

## mfootf {

```
position: relative;
width:100%;
height:115px;
border:thin solid black;
```

}
-->

Comment: Why do you need position:relative on your layout divs? I can't remember ever having done that - and I've made a lot of layouts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `width:100%;` should make the div 100% in width, assuming there are no margins or paddings on your body/div. Remove those and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Yes it does, unless you're adding some other constraint.

Comment: As I mentioned above I cannot use absolute property for dynamic content.

Comment: I'm not asking you to. And you don't have to specify a `position` property at all for the most part.

Comment: Ya! correct! but doing so how can I set my width to complete 100%? Its not working.

Comment: "its not working" isn't a very good description of the problem. _What_ isn't working? How does it look? How do you expect it to look?

Comment: I got my answer. The issue by used the above CSS properties as mentioned in my code when I set width to 100% it just gives up to some 95% or something but not full. But now I got it. I am posting my answer below.

Comment: +1 because you solved the user's problem, even if he doesn't want to admit it.